# Looking for a good solution for refactoring an Android GATT architecture of BLE(Bluetooth Low Energy)

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am looking for a good solution for refactoring an architecture of BLE which was developed by my colleague. What the scope of the code performs is putting a GATT connection into a Service, but doing nothing nothing with the lifecycle of the Service, below is the onStartCommand of the Service looks like:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

then code goes like generating a public function named "connect" into the Service for connecting GATT via the context of Service, below is the function looks like:

```
public boolean connect(String address) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
        return false;
    }
    BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt = null;

    BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (bluetoothDevice == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        return false;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        bluetoothGatt = bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(this, false, createGattCallback(address));
    } else {
        bluetoothGatt = bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(this, false, createGattCallback(address), 
    BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE);
        if (null != bluetoothGatt)
            bluetoothGatt.requestConnectionPriority(BluetoothGatt.CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH);
    }
    return true;
}
```

well this is very odd to me because the whole thing sounds like "You never use a lifecycle of the Service, but you always use the context of the Service."

And then the code saves the gatt object as a member variable at the Service until the BLE connection is disconnected, also generates some public methods like writing characteristic and disconnecting for communicating with Bluetooth device via the gatt object, so I think the whole code uses nothing about the feature of Service but only puts some public methods into Service.

I have several questions below:

1. Should I have to combine a gatt architecture into Service?
2. As I mentioned above that the gatt used the context of Service, what if I keep the code goes like that and what would happen when the Service is destroyed but the gatt is still connected?
3. Is there any good idea for an architecture of GATT?

Comment: Do you know about [RxAndroidBle](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle)? One of the best BLE library ever

Comment: @M D, I will be counting on that later in another project, thx, but for now I have no plan to use third-part library into this project I have to refactor.

Comment: That context parameter sent to connectGatt is never used by Android internally (at least in non-ancient versions), so it doesn't matter if service is destroyed.

Comment: @Emil Thanks, man, I am going to migrate the code to JobScheduler.